# How to delete Last Opened date on Mac OSX Finder

Tags: mac, terminal, finder, macos-catalina, touch

I am trying to delete the "Last Opened" date for a file found in Finder on Mac OSX (Catalina 10.15.7).

I've found a few walkthroughs already and tried them without success. In Terminal I have used "touch -mt", and "xattr -d" commands, but neither work for me.

Here are some of my latest attempts (I'm not sure of the formatting, hence the multiple versions of the xattr comment):

- > touch -mt 201801010101 /file-location*
- > xattr -d com.apple.metadata:kMDItemLastUsedDate /file-location
- > xattr -w "com.apple.metadata:kMDItemLastUsedDate" "01/01/2000" /file-location
- > xattr -d com.apple.lastuseddate /file-location
- > xattr -d "com.apple.lastuseddate" /file-location

Can anyone please help me to either correct the commands I have attempted, or provide another solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
xattr -d 'com.apple.lastuseddate#PS' /file-location
```

As far as I've been able to find out, this is where the last opened date is stored. But deleting it didn't change what the Finder showed when I tried it. I thought it might also be cached in the folder's `.DS_Store` file, but removing that didn't clear it, either.

But this is probably the first step.